# Панель состояния: задать значение метке панели управления текстовго редактора

Tags: c#

Какое надо задать значение метке панели управления текстовго редактора, чтобы отображалось имя редактируемого в этот момент текстового файла?

Comment: Метке панели? А что это такое?

Comment: Кому как, я совсем зеленый в программировании. Можно поподробнее о <current file name>, как именно прописывать?

Comment: Ну, вы когда открываете файл, вы его имя знаете? Оно у вас где-то в строковой переменной. Вот это оно и есть.

Comment: Я его открываю через диалоговое окно, в методе у меня прописан OFD.FileName = "text.txt"; Но ведь это не то.

Comment: @Korol_tref: А что вы делаете _после_ того, как диалоговое окно закрылось?

Comment: >Я его открываю через диалоговое окно, в методе у меня прописан OFD.FileName = "text.txt"; Но ведь это не то.

во-первых, зачем вам жестко прописывать название файла? Это текстовый редактор для одного файла на свете? 
во-вторых, если уж вы его прописываете жестко, то зачем вам  диалоговое окно?
в-третьих, вы сами ответили на вопрос про <current file name> - это тот самый "text.txt"

Comment: @DreamChild: я думаю, таким образом получается имя файла «по умолчанию», а настоящее имя пользователь может изменить в диалоге.

Comment: @VladD ну даже если это "имя по умолчанию" для нового файла, то все равно же получается, что в текущий момент пользователь редактирует файл "text.txt", а следовательно нужно отображать именно это имя

Comment: В методе прописано такое имя по умолчанию, но я могу выбрать другой файл, с другим именем... Так вот откуда мне выдрать эту переменную, этого  имени файла?

Comment: @DreamChild: Если так, то его и надо использовать.

@Korol_tref: А вы откуда берёте имя файла после того, как юзер нажал OK в диалоге? Читайте внимательно свой же код.

Comment: void OpenFile()
        {           
            StreamReader SR;
            OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
            OFD.FileName = "text.txt";
            OFD.Filter = "TXT (*.txt)|*.txt|RTF (*.rtf)|*.rtf|TXT&RTF (*.txt; *.rtf)|*.txt; *.rtf";

            if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SR = new StreamReader(OFD.FileName);
                richTextBox1.Text = SR.ReadToEnd();
                SR.Close();
            }
        }

Я могу выбрать другой файл и имя автоматически перепишется, но хз как это имя вбить в Label.

Comment: @Korol_tref пожалуйста без подзаборной ругани. Вы же не быдло какое-нибудь, надеюсь? Формулируйте вопрос грамотнее. 

Из вашего же кода: **OFD.FileName** - это то, что вам нужно. Когда открываете новый файл, обновляйте содержимое Label - вполне очевидное действие

Comment: @Korol_tref: О, видите, уже лучше. У вас же написано:

    SR = new StreamReader(OFD.FileName);

Значит, имя файла лежит ... (где?)

Надеюсь, передать значение строковой переменной в другую процедуру вы сможете. (Если нет, проблема глубже.)

Comment: Да, не быдло, но эмоции уже в захлеб... Код я сам писал. Имя вбил заранее, но я могу выбрать другой файл и имя автоматически перепишется, на имя того файла, который я выбрал, и тогда то имя, что задано у меня по умолчанию мне не нужно уже.

Comment: @Korol_tref по-моему, вы задумали что-то страшное. Зачем вам имя по умолчанию? Вероятно, чтобы назначить его едва только созданному файлу, у которого вообще нет никакого имени. Или я ошибаюсь? 
Если вы открываете другой файл, то его имя можете получить через **OFD.FileName** и тут же записать его в Label или куда вам там надо. Открыли файл - обновили Label, открыли другой файл - снова обновили. И так далее. В таком случае вам ваше "имя по умолчанию" понадобится только для новых файлов без имени и не понадобится вам до тех пор пока вы не создадите новый файл. Все просто

Comment: Кому просто, а кому и нет. Моих знаний видимо совсем мало. Мне требуется прописать в таймере OFD.FileName, но переменная видимо не доживает до этого события. Как можно ее указать из метода или как мне вообще это сделать?

Comment: таймер-то вам зачем? Вы хотите обновлять Label по таймеру? Так с ней ничего не случится и без таймера до тех пор, пока вы ее не измените сами

Comment: @Korol_tref: Заведите себе хранилище информации о текущем файле. Сохраняйте имя туда. При необходимости доставайте его оттуда.

Где именно и как — да как угодно, хоть в `Application`-классе.

Comment: Уточнили бы, какая библиотека используется (WPF, WinForms, ...)